# compare extracted date with today() in excel

Tags: date, excel-formula

Column 1 : I have this date-time format in one column = `2018-10-08T04:30:23Z`

Column 3 : I extracted date with formula = `=LEFT(A11,10)` and changed column format to date.

Column 32 : `today()`. Just to make sure both date columns match

Now when I want to compare both dates

Column 4 : `=IF(C11=D11,TRUE(),FALSE())`

It does not work. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option using formulas only would be to use Excel's `DATE` function, which takes three parameters:

```
=DATE(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)
```

Use the following formula to extract a date from your timestamp:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4), MID(A1,6,2), MID(A1,9,2))
```

This assumes that the timestamp is in cell `A1`, with the format in your question.  Now, comparing this date value against `TODAY()` should work, if the original timestamp were also from today.

Comment: Tim's solution should work. Using Evaluate Formula you can see that `=LEFT(A11,10)` will be treated as a text and not as date. So when the formula in column 4 tries to evaluate the two cells it will return FALSE as one is text cell and the other is date.

Answer (score 0):

Should be worth trying:

```
=1*LEFT(A1,10)=TODAY()
```

May depend upon your configuration. Without format conversion (the `1*`) you are trying to compare text (all string functions return Text) with a Number.